# Ajax (POST) Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, post

Estou tendo o famoso erro 419, que por um determinado momento consegui resolver, porém após reiniciar o server, parou de funcionar.

Route:

```
Route::post('ajax/Register', 'Ajax@Register');
```

Controller:

```
public static function Register()
{
    $input = request()->all();

    return $input;
}
```

META TAG:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

JS:

```
var _token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');

$.ajaxSetup({

    headers: {

        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token

    }

});

$('#formRegister').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/Register',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'user': 'oi'
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',

        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Network:

```
Status Code: 419 unknown status
Request Headers > X-CSRF-TOKEN: oAiZm9n8xByExejoRVT3Yv2WKxkmoN1uZHkzHuAR
```

Ou seja, o ajax de fato envia o token, porém não tenho sucesso na operação do POST.

Comment: Se você registrar a rota no Middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` (dentro do array `$except`), ele não vai apresentar mais o erro para esta rota.

Comment: Poderia elaborar melhor a resposta colocando o porque você acredita que essas modificações vão resolver o problema? Assim ajudará melhor outras pessoas a entender seu raciocínio :)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece pq vc precisa adicionar o CSRF no payload que você vai mandar para o servidor, e não nos HEADERS.

```
data: {
_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
}
```

Acredito que isso deva resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvendo seu problema de cair no erro 419... Primeiro altere sua rota para:

```
Route::post('ajaxRegister', ['as' => 'ajax.register', 'uses' => 'Ajax@Register']);
```

Logo após atualize no ajax para:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('ajax.register') }}",
    data: {
        'user': 'oi'
    },   
...
```

A principio seu Controller está correto, uma dica que posso dar é sobre o método do `Controller` é a seguinte:

```
public function Register(Request $request)
{
    $dados = $request->all(); // ou
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
         ......
}
```

> Sua dúvida é parecida com outra recente aqui no fórum, de uma olhada
>   aqui:
>
> [Completar form sem dar reload na página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337983/completar-form-sem-dar-reload-na-p%C3%A1gina/337997)