# Completar form sem dar reload na página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, laravel

Estou tentando implementar uma página onde poderão ser alterados os valores de uma tabela cadastrados no banco de um sistema.

Ao selecionar o nome das pessoas listadas, eu chamo a função `ola` através do `onchange`, o que está funcionando perfeitamente, mas ao tentar atualizar os valores cadastrados nos `inputs` do `form`, não consigo.

Esta é minha função:

```
function ola(val){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })
    $.ajax({
        url:'editarInstalador',
        data:{pid:val},         
        type:"POST",
        data:{pid:val},
        success:function(data){

        },
        error:function(data){

        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

A minha rota:

```
Route::post('editarInstalador', 'instaladorController@edit');
```

A função no controller:

```
public function edit()
{
    $json = array();
    $idPessoa = request("pid");
    $instaladorDados =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM public.tblInstalador WHERE inst_id = {$idPessoa}");
    foreach ($instaladorDados as $var) {
        $json[]= array(
                'nomee' => $var->inst_razaosocial,
                'nomeFantasia' => $var->inst_nomefantasia,
                'cnpj' => $var->inst_cnpj,
            );
    }
    return response()->json($json);
}
```

Estou conseguindo chamar perfeitamente o `controller`, fazer a pesquisa no banco e como resposta eu tenho no `response` do navegador:

```
[{"nomee":"nomeCadastrado","nomeFantasia":"daniel franca","cnpj":"cnpj cadastrado"}]
```

O meu problema é que primeiramente, no `$.ajax` onde chamo a rota, ele literalmente sempre entra no `error`, nunca entra no `success`.

A minha segunda dúvida é: como posso passar esta resposta para a `view` e preencher os `inputs` com estes dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvendo seu problema de cair no `error` logo ao enviar os dados...
Primeiro altere sua rota para:

```
Route::post('editarInstalador', ['as' => 'editar.editarInstalador', 'uses' => 'instaladorController@edit']);
```

Logo após atualize no ajax para:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('editar.editarInstalador')}}",
    data:{pid:val},     
...
```

A principio seu `Controller` está correto, a forma de retornar o `json` para o `ajax`, você só precisa tratar o retorno da forma que for necessário, verifique como a resposta chega no `callback` de `success` com o `console.log(data)`, uma dica que posso dar é sobre o método do `Controller`:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $idPessoa = $request->only("pid");
    $instaladorDados =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM public.tblInstalador WHERE inst_id = {$idPessoa}");
    foreach ($instaladorDados as $var) {
        $json[]= array(
                'nomee' => $var->inst_razaosocial,
                'nomeFantasia' => $var->inst_nomefantasia,
                'cnpj' => $var->inst_cnpj,
            );
    }
    return response()->json($json);
}
```

Ps: Considere usar os `Models` ao invés de buscar os dados com `Query Builders` simples assim.

Sobre a manipulação do retorno você pode acessar os objetos retornados buscando pela posição e atributo de cada item. A forma mais crua e rustica é:

```
<input id="inputNome" name="inputNome">

$('#inputNome').val(data[0].nomee);
```

Caso você tenha mais de um resultado no `array` de objetos retornados, considere usar um laço `each`, considere também a possibilidade de usar o `JSON.parse()` no retorno do `data`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, a questão da rota funcionou perfeitamente e agora ele entra no success corretamente.
Tive como resposta no console: 
[{…}]
0: {nomee: "nomeCadastrado", nomeFantasia: "NomeFantasia", cnpj: "cnpj cadastrado"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
Por favor, o senhor poderia me dar um exemplo de como posso jogar estes valores para os inputs? 
Novamente agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Eu resolvi utilizando o código:
success:function(data){
    $("#testee").attr({value:data[0].nomee});
    
},
Novamente agradeço pela atenção.   Att.

Comment: Acabei de editar a resposta, mas é isso mesmo que você comentou